# Need 2 pixel solid color gap between boxes

Tags: css

I need to add a two pixel gap with a solid color between the services boxes below ie location contact etc can you please tell me how I have tried padding-right:2px and changing background color but that did not work its pulling my hair out thanks

http://indigo.websitewelcome.com/~memorialpodiatry/

I have tried the following code to add the border to the right of the divs and it works ok but obviouslly i do not want the border on the last div.

```
.moduletable-blocks {
width: 340px;
float: left;
margin: 0 7px 0 0;  
padding: 0 0 17px;
border-right:2px solid #f2d8b5

}



.moduletable-blocks .last { border-right:none; }
```

As you see I was using the last selection to try and set border to none any ideas.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 please see above edits any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want a border on your last div use this

```
.moduletable-blocks:last-child { 
     border-right:none; 
}
```